# How to find out which backported packages are available, and avoid losing packages when manually upgrading?

Tags: apt, backport

I was surprised to see that since Natty 11.04, even when we have *enabled* a backports repository, updated packages aren't *automatically installed* from that repository. We have to install individual updates manually, e.g. via

```
apt-get install ipython/precise-backports
```

as explained at [UbuntuBackports - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports).  I guess I just didn't get the memo....

First question: how do we find out what our options are for upgrades via backports?  I'm surprised that even if I ask for status, e.g. via

```
wajig status ipython
```

it doesn't tell me there is a new version available.  I'd like a list of all upgrades for packages which I've already installed.

Next, how do I avoid losing existing packages just because I upgrade via a backport?

E.g. the above ipython install tells me:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
   ipython-notebook ipython-qtconsole
```

How do I say I want the latest backported ipython, as well as any other packages for which updates are available that depend on it, without manually figuring them all out and installing them also?

I know I can change the pinning so that I get **all** updates, but I'm hesitant to go against the general advice not to.  But if a user asks for one package to be updated, wouldn't it be natural to update all the dependencies, like you'd get from a ppa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how do we find out what our options are for upgrades via backports?

Run apt-get with the `--default-release` or `-t` switch:

```
sudo apt-get -t precise-backports upgrade
```

Is the same as `apt-get install ipython/precise-backports` just that you don't have to insert the `precise-backports` part.

> I'm surprised that even if I ask for status, e.g. via `wajig status ipython` it doesn't tell me there is a new version available.

For that I use `apt-cache policy`:

```
apt-cache policy iceweasel
iceweasel:
  Installed: 25.0~a2+20130816004007-1~bpo70+1
  Candidate: 25.0~a2+20130816004007-1~bpo70+1
  Package pin: 25.0~a2+20130816004007-1~bpo70+1
  Version table:
 *** 25.0~a2+20130816004007-1~bpo70+1 1990
       1990 http://mozilla.debian.net/ wheezy-backports/iceweasel-aurora i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     23.0-2 1990
         -1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ experimental/main i386 Packages
     17.0.8esr-2 1990
        990 http://ftp.utexas.edu/debian/ testing/main i386 Packages
         -1 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ sid/main i386 Packages
```

> Next, how do I avoid losing existing packages just because I upgrade via a backport?

If the packages you want to upgrade break previous dependencies, then you should decide if upgrading or leaving things as they are. Or you just force things down and break your installation, is all up to you.

> How do I say I want the latest backported ipython, as well as any other packages for which updates are available that depend on it, without manually figuring them all out and installing them also?

Same as above.

> But if a user asks for one package to be updated, wouldn't it be natural to update all the dependencies, like you'd get from a ppa?

If there is no update candidates, no. This happens a lot on rolling releases distributions, some packages depend of others that are yet no available in the repositories, so apt decides no to upgrade since it breaks dependencies.

For the case of `ipython` that you mention on comments:

Following the [package dependencies page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-backports/ipython-notebook) `ipython-notebook=0.13.2-1~ubuntu12.04.1` depends to `ipython=0.13.2-1~ubuntu12.04.1`, but if you try to upgrade `ipython` alone, apt will take your actions as priority and fulfill them at any cost. Since you are only telling apt to install `ipython` from backports, he understand:

> Fulfill **only** this condition at any cost

So, the only way to do this is removing/downgrading any package that gets it dependencies broken due this operation (`ipython-notebook`) and install `ipython` from backports. The correct way to do this is, either:

```
sudo apt-get -t precise-backports install ipython-notebook ipython
```

or

```
sudo apt-get -t precise-backports upgrade
```

The first one will tell apt-get to install `ipython-notebook` and `ipython` from backports, the second will tell apt to upgrade any installed package that has upgrades in the `precise-backports` repository.

Comment: Very helpful.  Thanks!  But on the last question: as I noted, even available binary packages from the same source package, which are in backports, don't get upgraded and are removed instead, like ipython-notebook.  When would that ever be a user's intent?  Can that be fixed/avoided?

Comment: You should check the `apt-cache depends ipython-notebook` if it has an entry like: `Depends: ipython=1.2.3` also, the new packages that could be installed that can cause dependencies conflict.

Comment: Sure, ipython-notebook says "Depends: ipython".  So if I have ipython-notebook 0.12.1 installed, as well as ipython 0.12.1 (both from the same source package to boot), and 0.13.1 is in backports, and I upgrade ipython, why would it choose to remove ipython-notebook rather than upgrade it (and install Depends: ipython-notebook-common, a new dependency package in that version)

Comment: @nealmcb check my answer updated

Comment: Cool - I was hoping that -t would work that way also.  But what if it was just "sudo apt-get -t precise-backports install ipython" - might that also be smart enough to properly upgrade ipython-notebook and ipython-qtconsole also?

Comment: he's smart enough to **not** do what you didn't ask him to do. You asked him *install this package from this repository*, and that's exactly what he does. Since the other packages get broken he removes them. Now, if you do `apt-get -t precise-backports install ipython-notebook` he will upgrade `ipython` since you are asking him *install this package from this repository and all its dependencies*. If `ipython-notebook` didn't specified what version to install, you would have noticed that with the last operand, it wouldn't try to upgrade `ipython` or with the former, remove `ipython-notebook`.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. OK, I agree that given the unambiguous meaning of the commands given, that's what apt has to do. So I guess I'm looking for a different command that would "do the right thing" for this sort of common case and make it easier to upgrade, e.g., all the binary packages that come from a given backported source package and are currently installed or are new and required. Perhaps it could just look for anything it is removing and see if that exists in the repository specified by -t.  I'm basically trying to get closer to the ease of upgrades when backports aren't pinned low.